# Mysqli connection using object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just started switching my project form the mysql to mysqli. So what i did is i just create a class db and function connect.how can i create objects and re use it

This is my code:

**class db:**

```
class db {

    //global var session
    private $biz;

    //constructor
    function db (&$b) {
        $this->biz = $b;            
        $this->connect();
    }

    function connect() {
        mysqli_connect(
              $this->biz->_db['host']
            , $this->biz->_db['username']
            , $this->biz->_db['password']
                        ,$this->biz->_db['database']
        ) or die("Unable to connect to database");

        //$cont=mysqli_select_db($con,$this->biz->_db['database']) or die("Unable to select database: {$this->biz->_db['database']}");
        //return $connt;
    }       

    /*
     This function will perform a simple query and return all the results
     @return        object      Object containing the rows, num_rows and result

     @param string  $sql        The SQL query
    */
    function query($sql) {

            $result = new fetchQuery($sql);
            return $result;
    }

    /*
     This function will perform a query given the sql
     @return        object      Object containing num rows affected and result

     @param string  $sql        The SQL query
    */
    function updateQuery($sql) {
        return new updateQuery($sql);
    }

    /*
     This function will perform a query given the sql
     @return        object      Object containing num rows affected and result

     @param string  $sql        The SQL query
    */
    function insertQuery($sql) {    
        return new insertQuery($sql);
    }

    /*
     This function will perform a query given the sql
     @return        object      Object containing num rows affected and result

     @param string  $sql        The SQL query
    */
    function deleteQuery($sql) {
        return new deleteQuery($sql);
    }

    /*
     This function will automatically decide if data is being updated or inserted

     @param array   $data       The post object, key/value pairs , already validated
     @param string  $table      The table to be updated
    */       

    /*
     This function will perform an update query from the post data that has the correct form - fields matching table field names
     @return        object      Object containing num rows affected and result

     @param array   $data       The post object, key/value pairs , already validated
     @param string  $table      The table to be updated
    */
    function autoUpdate($data, $table,$wheredata) {

        //id is required, return false if not found
        if (!isset($wheredata)) 
        {
            return false;
        }  

        $sql = "
            UPDATE
                `$table`
            SET
        ";

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {          
                $sql .= " `$key` = '$value' ,";     
        }

        //remove extra comma
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, (strlen($sql) - 1));         
        $sql .= " WHERE 0=0 ";

        foreach ($wheredata as $key => $value) {
        $sql .= " and `$key` = '$value' ";
        }

        return new updateQuery($sql);
    }

    /*
     This function will perform an insert query from the matching form table
     @return        object      Object containing num rows affected and result

     @param array   $data       The post object, key/value pairs , already validated
     @param string  $table      The table to be updated
    */
    function autoInsert($data, $table, $validate = false)
    {
        $_fields = array();
        $_values = array();

        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            $_fields[] = $field;
            $_values[] = $value;
        }

        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO
                `$table`
                    (
        ";

        foreach($_fields as $field) {
            $sql .= "`$field` ,";
        }

        //remove extra comma
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, (strlen($sql) - 1));

        $sql .= "
            ) VALUES (
        ";

        foreach($_values as $value) {
            $sql .= "'$value' ,";
        }

        //remove extra comma
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, (strlen($sql) - 1));

        $sql .= "
            )
        ";

        return new insertQuery($sql);
    }

    /*
     This function will perform an auto delete query from the matching form table
     @return        object      Object containing num rows affected and result

     @param int     $id         The related id
     @param string  $table      The table to be affected
    */
    function autoDelete($sql) {         
        return new deleteQuery($sql);       }
}
```

**fetch query:**

```
class fetchQuery {

    public $result;
    public $num = 0;
    public $rows = array();
    public $error = false;

    function fetchQuery($sql) {

        $this->result = mysql_query($sql);    

        if ($this->result) {
            $this->num = mysql_num_rows($this->result);
            if ($this->num) {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result)) {
                    $this->rows[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $this->result = false;
            }
        } else {
            $this->result = false;
            $this->error  = mysql_error();
        }
    }
```

please give me a solution for create fetch query using connect function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: First of all, now you mix mysqli and mysql functions. Second, I think this is not a good design. Why don't you create one Database class, where everything is happens and stores?

Comment: I want to change it to mysqli like  mysqli_query($con,$sql).my doubt is that from where i create $con and how to access it to fetchQuery function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a structure like below and try

Database Configuration : dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$glob['dbhost'] = 'localhost'; 
$glob['dbusername'] = 'username'; 
$glob['dbpassword'] =  'password'; 
$glob['dbdatabase'] = 'database';  
?>
```

Database Class : database.class.php

```
<?php

class database {

var $_sql           = '';   
/** @var Internal variable to hold the connector resource */
var $_resource      = '';
/** @var Internal variable to hold the query result*/
var $_result        = ''; 

/**
* Database object constructor
* @param string Database host
* @param string Database user name
* @param string Database user password
* @param string Database name
*/
function database() {
    global $glob;
    $host = $glob['dbhost'];
    $user = $glob['dbusername'];
    $pass = $glob['dbpassword'];
    $db = $glob['dbdatabase'];
    $this->_resource = @mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db );
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else{
        echo "Could not connect to the database!";
        exit;
    }               
}

/**
* Execute the query
* @return mixed A database resource if successful, FALSE if not.
*/
function query($sql) {
    $_sql = $sql;
    return $_result = @mysqli_query($this->_resource, $_sql);               
}

function fetchArray($result) {
    return @mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

function fetchAssoc($result) {
    return @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
}
?>
```

Project Configuration : configuration.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
@ob_gzhandler();
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

require_once('dbconfig.php');

require_once('database.class.php');
$dbclass = new database();
?>
```

Any project file code :

```
<?php
require('configuration.php');

$sqltepm="SELECT * FROM tblname";
$restepm=$dbclass->query($sqltepm);
while($row=$dbclass->fetchArray($restepm)){
    extract($row);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a basic function like strategy to handle this type of Scenario. Hence if you include the function file alone your DB will be connected on the fly and you can use this using the variable that you connect to the DB.

You can have two files and then you can perform the scenario like this.

**db.php**

```
<?php
class DB {
    function __construct(){
        $username='root';
        $password='';
        $host='localhost';
        $db='store';
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($username,$password,$host,$db);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno){
            echo "Failed to connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }

    function fetchData(){
        $get_query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $get_query);
    }

}
?>
```

And you can call the function in the page as follows.

> Usage of the class that we have created

**listpage.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php'); // Include the DB file over this line
$conn= new DB(); // Initialize the class that we have created
$conn->fetchData();// This query will select all the data and return it.
?>
```

I hope so my explanation over the code are clear and you can understand it well and continue your project codes on the fly.

Happy Coding :)